# Get child table by ORM relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Given a table that has a relation:

```
class Child(Model):
    ...
    parent = relationship('Parent')
```

If we have an instance `child = Child(...)` of the class and an `InstrumentedAttribute` `attr = Child.parent` of one of the class's relationships<sup>1</sup>, is there a clean way to get the related object of the instance (i.e. `child.parent` in this case)?  Doing

```
getattr(child, attr.key)
```

works, of course, but using reflection when we have a "proper" accessor is a pretty questionable code smell.  (It also depends on the lower-level `.key` API for the high-level task of accessing an attribute, which is also smelly.)

The reason behind this question is that I am writing generic code to be used on multiple tables, where the relationship is specified at the call site.  This means that `child.parent` will not work, as the relationship to be used might not be called `parent`.  (The name could be passed in as an additional string argument, but then we're back to using `getattr`.)

Is there a more idiomatic way to do this?

---

<sup>1</sup> Presumably, a solution would also work for `InstrumentedAttribute`s of vanilla columns as well, but that's not a requirement.

Comment: Can't you do `child.parent` to get at the Parent object? That results in execution of some SQL (separate from the contruction/selection of the Child object), but a query can use `options(joinedload(..))` to cause the initial underlying query to extract the .parent related object.

Comment: @CodeMantle Normally, yes, but I'm writing table-agnostic code, so that isn't an option here.  I'll edit that into the question.